# An Artinian ring which is not Noetherian

Tags: ring-theory

Find an example of a ring which is Artinian but not Noetherian.

Since a commutative Artinian ring is Noetherian , I know I have to look for a non- commutative Artinian ring.

To start with a non-commutative ring, I can only think of Matrix rings. But I am not getting anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If rings are not supposed to be unital, the classical counterexample is the trivial ring on the Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ that is Artinian, but not Noetherian (and it is obviously commutative).

If rings are unital, then every right (or left) Artinian ring is right (or left) Noetherian ([Hopkins-Levitzki theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem)).